# no results when executing Python Script

Tags: python, mininet

Im new to python and trying to have this python script to create a very simple custom topology in mininet in an Ubuntu live server
However, when I enter "sudo Python SDN.py" it gives no result whatsoever

```
from mininet.topo import Topo  
class MyTopo( Topo ):  
    "Simple topology example."
    def __init__( self ):
        "Create custom topo."

        # Initialize topology
        Topo.__init__( self )

        # Add hosts and switches
        hostx = self.addHost( 'h1' )
        Sw1 = self.addSwitch('s1')

        # Add links
        self.addLink( Hostx, Sw1 )
        topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }
```

any help is welcome, please note i'm only day 2 into python

Answer (score 2):

You're never actually running anything! Take this for example:

```
def func(a):
    print(a)
```

This snippet won't do anything unless you actually make a call to the function, like this:

```
func("test")
```

Comment: To add to this - In most programming languages, when writing functions, there's normally a difference between _saying what you want to do_ and actually _doing it_. So here you've told Python **what** you want to do **when you run the function**. If you don't actually tell Python to run the function, nothing happens.